# ajax not returning value from the mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am hoping to be able to use .post method to send variables to a php file where I could be able to retrieve data from database with mysql query. So far I can send information about the variable using ajax but not able to retrieve output from the php script using ajax. I am very immature to ajax, hence learning through errors...Thanks for looking into my query.

How can I get to display php output within the div tag of index.php

**test.php**

```
   <?php require('../config/connection.php'); ?>
        <?php
        $value = $_POST['value'];
        $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT DISTINCT class,product FROM prdct_categories WHERE class = '$value'");
        while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $prdct = $list['product'];
        echo $prdct;    
        }
   ?>
```

**ajax code (index.php)**

```
    <div class="col-md-2" >

         <?php

        $test  = $_GET['product'];
        $q = "SELECT * FROM prdct_categories WHERE product = '$test' ";
        $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        $path_info = get_path();
        $test1 = $path_info['call_parts'][1];

       While($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {?>
      <li class="nav" <?php if($test1==$list['slugs']){echo'id="actives"';} ?>>

<a href="<?php echo $test;?>/<?php echo $list['slugs'];?> ">

<?php echo $list['subgroup']."(".$list['contains'].")".'<br/>';?></a></li>

                 <?php }?>   
                 </div>

                <div class="col-md-4" id="testing">

                </div>

                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                        $(".nav").click(function(){

                        $.post("test.php", {value:$(this).text()}, function(data) {$("#testing").text(data)} );

                        event.preventDefault();
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in your browser's developer tools?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and make sure you've loaded the jQuery library.

Comment: [How To](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php)

Comment: Can you share a sample of your `.nav` HTML?

Comment: I just executed your code in my system. It worked fine *Alga - Prakaar*

Comment: @PeterKA updated question with .nav script

Comment: Thanks @GautamPBehera. Usually a *sample* of the generated HTML is more helpful that the script you've provided. Take a look at the answer I have provided below.

Comment: `id='nav'` in html and using `.nav` in script.

Comment: Apologies...copied & pasted the incorrect bit @NanaPartykar

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code instead. You do have to prevent the default action of the links that you're clicking within the `.nav` elements:

```
    $(".nav > a").click(function(e){ // see change here
            e.preventDefault();   // added here e must match var e above.
            $.post("test.php", {value:$(this).text()}, function(data) {$("#testing").text(data)} );
    });
```

And your `.nav` script should be:

```
<li class="nav<?php if($pageid==$nav['product']){echo ' active';}?>"> 
....
```

Your current script does not create any elements with `class="nav"` and therefore, the selector `.nav` returns nothing. ***Your current script also creates several elements with the same id, `id="nav"`, which makes your HTML invalid..*** Make the above changes and

Comment: I am getting this notice but not the output from database also apology about the confusion. Please check my updated nav bit...
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\series\dynamics\admin\CleanURL\test.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br /> Array

Comment: In effect you're confirming that the above changes indeed do work, in that you're now getting a response from `test.php`, only that the php script needs to be fixed, right? If this is so, would it be better to ask a new **PHP** question?

Answer (score 0):

Form to return data from ajax.

```
<?php require('../config/connection.php'); 
      header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $value = $_POST['value'];
        $prdct = array();
        $query = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT DISTINCT product FROM prdct_categories WHERE class LIKE '{$value}'");
        while($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $prdct[] = $list['product'];
        }
        $return = json_encode($prdct);
        echo $return;
        die;
   ?>
```

In javascript replace:

```
$.post("test.php", {value:$(this).text()}, function(data) {$("#testing").text(data)} );
```

to

```
$.post("test.php", {value:$(this).text()}, function(data){
    for(var k in data) {
    $("#testing").append(data[k]+"<br />");
    }
});
```

Comment: In your javascript, data is a list to results. Use console.log(data) and view in console firebug or console chrome to see the elements.

Comment: this is the output [], with above changes

Comment: So, your query return empty.

Comment: try : "SELECT DISTINCT product FROM prdct_categories WHERE class LIKE '{$value}'"

Comment: And in your javascript, to set text o code in de tag, use html for example. I edit my answer.

Comment: my error in the php.. correct return is: $return = json_encode($prdct); echo $return;

Answer (score 0):

Use `$("#testing").html(data);` instead of `$("#testing").text(data);`

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nav").click(function(){
              $.post("test.php", {value:$(this).text()}, function(data) {
                        $("#testing").html(data);
                    });
              event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: using .tml doesn't make any difference to the output